# string replacement in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How to replace the below DECIMAL data type with DOUBLE using shell script?

**Source String:**

```
.
.
GROSS_AMOUNT  DECIMAL(11, 2)
.
.
```

**Result Should be:**

```
.
.
GROSS_AMOUNT  DOUBLE
.
.
```

Comment: This is straight forward `sed`, have you tried anything?

Comment: I have lots of DDL and i have to convert to BIGSQL data type, so i cant do manualy, thats the reason trying to do with script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="...GROSS_AMOUNT DECIMAL(11, 2)..."
str=$(sed 's/DECIMAL(.*)/DOUBLE/' <<< $str)
echo $str
```

This will output: `...GROSS_AMOUNT DOUBLE...`

Using `sed`, replace `DECIMAL(11, 2)` with whatever (in this case, `DOUBLE`).

Comment: this is for only one string, suppose if i get string in file with different length of DECIMAL like DECIMAL(5),DECIMAL(3,5)..how do i replace ?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "}$2{$2="DOUBLE"}1'
```

- Set Field Separator and Output Field Separator to two spaces
- If Field 2 exists, set it to `DOUBLE`
- Print